# Matrix hides row options in IE9

Tags: matrix

This is in response to the thread posted here: https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/matrix_in_ie9_hides_row_options which is no longer active.

Matrix 2.5.3 and Internet Explorer 9, the numbered tab on the left should give row options and the ability to reorder by dragging a dropping. In Firefox it works fine, however in IE9 no indicator shows there are row options and dragging to reorder doesn't work. Has there been any progress of resolving the issue?

Thanks!
-Steve

Answer (score 1):

sorry to say that no, not currently. I added this to the to-do list of our next version of Matrix, but I can't make any promises about when will that see the light of the day.

Could you shoot an email to support@pixelandtonic.com referencing this question? I'll check it out in the evening when I get access to a Windows machine.

Thanks!